# Python clear button

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Here is my simple Python calculator which takes a number and then it should return the number to the power of two. Example: I add number "5" to the entry and then calculator should return "25" to text window.

My problem is that how I can change the code that it clears the text window result? My goal is to make "Clear" button which clears the text window.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

def power_number():
    answer=float(e1_value.get())**2
    t1.insert(END,float(answer))

l1=Label(window,text="Number:")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

e1_value=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window,textvariable=e1_value)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

b1=Button(window,text="Calculate",command=power_number)
b1.grid(row=0,column=2)

t1=Text(window,height=1,width=15)
t1.grid(row=0,column=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete all command for the Text widget is:

```
t1.delete('0.0', END)
```

Comment: The index of the first character of a text widget is `"1.0"` not `"0.0"`.